# how to pass types as props in a reuseable component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a reusable component that i pass rows and headings to it as props where ever i use the component. the only problem i have is how to pass types as props to this component?

here is my reusable component

```
import { TableCell, TableRow } from "@mui/material";
import TableCellOperations from "./table-cell-operations.componenet";
import { PropertyListItem } from "@slice/properties.slice";

interface Props {
  rows?: PropertyListItem[];
  headings: HeadingsTypes[];
}

export interface HeadingsTypes {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  label: string;
}

const TableRowsComponent: React.FC<Props> = ({ rows, headings }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {rows?.map((row) => (
        <TableRow key={row.id}>
          {headings.map((heading) => (
            <TableCell key={heading.id} align="center">
              {typeof row[heading.id] === "object" && row[heading.id] !== null
                ? row[heading.id]?.title
                : heading.id === "status"
                ? row.status == 0
                  ? "منقضی"
                  : "فعال"
                : row[heading.id]}
            </TableCell>
          ))}
          <TableCellOperations />
        </TableRow>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default TableRowsComponent;
```

my rows type could be diffrent by situation. in here i put PropertyListItem as rows types but maybe types of rows change. so i want to pass type of rows as a props to this reuseable component. what should i do?

Comment: It doesn't make sense because types exist only at compile-time. They don't exist at runtime in Javascript, so it doesn't make sense to ask how to pass a compile-time type into a runtime data structure (props). Perhaps you are looking for [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to pass the type of rows as a prop to your reusable component is to use a generic type parameter in the component definition. Here's an example:

```
import { TableCell, TableRow } from "@mui/material";
import TableCellOperations from "./table-cell-operations.componenet";

interface Props<T> {
  rows?: T[];
  headings: HeadingsTypes[];
}

export interface HeadingsTypes {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  label: string;
}

const TableRowsComponent = <T extends Record<string, any>>({ rows, headings }: Props<T>) => {
  return (
    <>
      {rows?.map((row: T) => (
        <TableRow key={row.id}>
          {headings.map((heading) => (
            <TableCell key={heading.id} align="center">
              {typeof row[heading.id] === "object" && row[heading.id] !== null
                ? row[heading.id]?.title
                : heading.id === "status"
                ? row.status == 0
                  ? "منقضی"
                  : "فعال"
                : row[heading.id]}
            </TableCell>
          ))}
          <TableCellOperations />
        </TableRow>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default TableRowsComponent;
```

In this example, we've added a generic type parameter `T` to the component definition, which extends `Record<string, any>`. This means that `T` can be any object type. We've then used `T` as the type of the `rows` prop in the `Props` interface, and as the type of the `row` parameter in the `map` function.

When you use the `TableRowsComponent` in your code, you can specify the type of rows by passing it as the generic type argument, like this:

```
<TableRowsComponent<MyRowType> rows={myRows} headings={myHeadings} />
```

Replace `MyRowType` with the type of your rows.

Comment: Generic was the solution. tnx!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest making `TableRowsComponent` a generic using TS. This will allow you to use any type for the rows prop.

**Example**:

```
import { TableCell, TableRow } from "@mui/material";
import TableCellOperations from "./table-cell-operations.component";

interface Props<T> {
  rows?: T[];
  headings: HeadingsTypes[];
}

export interface HeadingsTypes {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  label: string;
}

const TableRowsComponent = <T, >({ rows, headings }: Props<T>): React.ReactElement => {
  return (
    <>
      {rows?.map((row, index) => (
        <TableRow key={index}>
          {headings.map((heading) => (
            <TableCell key={heading.id} align="center">
              {typeof (row as any)[heading.id] === "object" && (row as any)[heading.id] !== null
                ? (row as any)[heading.id]?.title
                : heading.id === "status"
                ? (row as any).status == 0
                  ? "منقضی"
                  : "فعال"
                : (row as any)[heading.id]}
            </TableCell>
          ))}
          <TableCellOperations />
        </TableRow>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default TableRowsComponent;
```

When you use `TableRowsComponent`, you will specify the type for rows like this:

```
import { YourType } from 'your-module'

<TableRowsComponent<YourType> rows={yourRows} headings={yourHeadings} />
```

Answer (score 1):

For those cases, you can use generic typing !

```
interface Props<T> {
  rows?: T[];
  headings: HeadingsTypes[];
}

const TableRowsComponent = <T>({ rows, headings }: Props<T>) => {
```

The type will then automatically be infer while passing a typed array into the prop `rows`

```
// Here the props of TableRowsComponent will be of type 
// Props<{id: string, name: string}>
<TableRowsComponent rows={[{id: '1', name: 'Hello'}]} />
```

[See the doc for more information](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html)